# Mongo Error : Invalid access at address: 0 Got signal: 11 (Segmentation fault)

Tags: mongodb

Out mongo server got shutdown yesterday. But We are unable to find its cause. Its showing Invalid access at address: 0 Got signal: 11 (Segmentation fault). We have full logs available. Please assist

```
2017-11-13T16:48:02.624+0000 I COMMAND  [conn29458] command autoload_new.$cmd command: update { update: "offers", updates: [ { q: { truck._id: ObjectId('577b83c0e6057b4639307720') }, u: { $set: { truck.acc_status: false, truck.speed: 0 } }, multi: true } ], ordered: true, writeConcern: { w: 1 } } keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:0 reslen:55 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 162, w: 162 } }, MMAPV1Journal: { acquireCount: { w: 324 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { w: 162 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { W: 162 }, acquireWaitCount: { W: 162 }, timeAcquiringMicros: { W: 443561 } } } 499ms
2017-11-13T16:48:02.635+0000 F -        [conn29458] Invalid access at address: 0
2017-11-13T16:48:02.677+0000 F -        [conn29458] Got signal: 11 (Segmentation fault).

 0xf5e489 0xf5dd52 0xf5e0ae 0x7f11765b3130 0x8344a1 0xaed483 0xaec9bb 0xad175f 0x9fd8a4 0x9fdbb9 0xa39e0c 0xbd09a4 0xbd0d54 0xbd13bd 0x9b1bdd 0x9b33bc 0x9b38fb 0x9b62ad 0x9d8474 0x9d93fd 0x9da10b 0xb9ef5a 0xab5290 0x80fc1d 0xf115bb 0x7f11765abdf5 0x7f117505a1ad
----- BEGIN BACKTRACE -----
{"backtrace":[{"b":"400000","o":"B5E489"},{"b":"400000","o":"B5DD52"},{"b":"400000","o":"B5E0AE"},{"b":"7F11765A4000","o":"F130"},{"b":"400000","o":"4344A1"},{"b":"400000","o":"6ED483"},{"b":"400000","o":"6EC9BB"},{"b":"400000","o":"6D175F"},{"b":"400000","o":"5FD8A4"},{"b":"400000","o":"5FDBB9"},{"b":"400000","o":"639E0C"},{"b":"400000","o":"7D09A4"},{"b":"400000","o":"7D0D54"},{"b":"400000","o":"7D13BD"},{"b":"400000","o":"5B1BDD"},{"b":"400000","o":"5B33BC"},{"b":"400000","o":"5B38FB"},{"b":"400000","o":"5B62AD"},{"b":"400000","o":"5D8474"},{"b":"400000","o":"5D93FD"},{"b":"400000","o":"5DA10B"},{"b":"400000","o":"79EF5A"},{"b":"400000","o":"6B5290"},{"b":"400000","o":"40FC1D"},{"b":"400000","o":"B115BB"},{"b":"7F11765A4000","o":"7DF5"},{"b":"7F1174F64000","o":"F61AD"}],"processInfo":{ "mongodbVersion" : "3.0.4", "gitVersion" : "0481c958daeb2969800511e7475dc66986fa9ed5", "uname" : { "sysname" : "Linux", "release" : "4.9.50-x86_64-linode86", "version" : "#1 SMP Thu Sep 14 19:28:20 UTC 2017", "machine" : "x86_64" }, "somap" : [ { "elfType" : 2, "b" : "400000", "buildId" : "69E53C6FFEE320204F7099893CA3B40309400897" }, { "b" : "7FFE46FA7000", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "996A37974939D28E9E59EA10D981157094A0F860" }, { "b" : "7F11765A4000", "path" : "/lib64/libpthread.so.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "12F30315D4F4A2FE58B1977405C8B5515861E66B" }, { "b" : "7F1176337000", "path" : "/lib64/libssl.so.10", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "BB96EE99138B19FECDAB55E80A1728B648ECAD50" }, { "b" : "7F1175F50000", "path" : "/lib64/libcrypto.so.10", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "B154203FB7C05AEE29D5D6F6C000305191209FE4" }, { "b" : "7F1175D48000", "path" : "/lib64/librt.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "7376A07360DC57189A8F92B20AA4AA1CAEA80551" }, { "b" : "7F1175B44000", "path" : "/lib64/libdl.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "4DFEE4EA9AE8FDD4C71BD4CCC0727222F19DF810" }, { "b" : "7F117583D000", "path" : "/lib64/libstdc++.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "405EACD649720B8668FFBBA197CBF030A7EF6296" }, { "b" : "7F117553B000", "path" : "/lib64/libm.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "A1AA62B29765BE03A36BF927B047EEEF8696EEC6" }, { "b" : "7F1175325000", "path" : "/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "6AA1DCC4DE7F1836344949857FC2017278631FFD" }, { "b" : "7F1174F64000", "path" : "/lib64/libc.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "C31FFE7942BFD77B2FCA8F9BD5709D387A86D3BC" }, { "b" : "7F11767C0000", "path" : "/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "9866E1D2BA61EBB4CE4F009FACDAACC24EF3B804" }, { "b" : "7F1174D18000", "path" : "/lib64/libgssapi_krb5.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "34672D541C8C9C5C1C25CB4F3F332CC9D3E604AD" }, { "b" : "7F1174A35000", "path" : "/lib64/libkrb5.so.3", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "45CB7F6CD322F5B55FF8B635F7EC1578631CCAEA" }, { "b" : "7F1174831000", "path" : "/lib64/libcom_err.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "3A1166709F88740C49E060731832E3FAD2DFB66B" }, { "b" : "7F11745FF000", "path" : "/lib64/libk5crypto.so.3", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "23A2D854538903E2B84EF0882046DD95522C8B59" }, { "b" : "7F11743E9000", "path" : "/lib64/libz.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "E45643F27F3B3E960F3691AFC6EC27A98EF7B46B" }, { "b" : "7F11741DA000", "path" : "/lib64/libkrb5support.so.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "F4A3D5E7E23F871751CA8F250421F8CF83447AD2" }, { "b" : "7F1173FD6000", "path" : "/lib64/libkeyutils.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "2E01D5AC08C1280D013AAB96B292AC58BC30A263" }, { "b" : "7F1173DBC000", "path" : "/lib64/libresolv.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "AC596E865AF0D14B10F7B707F47D2031AD6D68DC" }, { "b" : "7F1173B97000", "path" : "/lib64/libselinux.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "82FF6B18E1E42825CC2D060F969479AD4AF2F62C" }, { "b" : "7F1173936000", "path" : "/lib64/libpcre.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "298B19C64B19995F2AA4DA7B852E90BA5302F630" }, { "b" : "7F1173711000", "path" : "/lib64/liblzma.so.5", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "218D03D1F6CF1A099A4D467B5E8ECF4F2BF45750" } ] }}
 mongod(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x29) [0xf5e489]
 mongod(+0xB5DD52) [0xf5dd52]
 mongod(+0xB5E0AE) [0xf5e0ae]
 libpthread.so.0(+0xF130) [0x7f11765b3130]
 mongod(_ZNK5mongo7BSONObj8getFieldERKNS_10StringDataE+0x11) [0x8344a1]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo21getFieldDottedOrArrayERKNS_7BSONObjERKNS_8FieldRefEPm+0xA3) [0xaed483]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo19BSONElementIterator4moreEv+0x7B) [0xaec9bb]
 mongod(_ZNK5mongo19LeafMatchExpression7matchesEPKNS_17MatchableDocumentEPNS_12MatchDetailsE+0x7F) [0xad175f]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo14CollectionScan15returnIfMatchesEPNS_16WorkingSetMemberEmPm+0x44) [0x9fd8a4]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo14CollectionScan4workEPm+0x2C9) [0x9fdbb9]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo11UpdateStage4workEPm+0x7C) [0xa39e0c]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo12PlanExecutor18getNextSnapshottedEPNS_11SnapshottedINS_7BSONObjEEEPNS_8RecordIdE+0xA4) [0xbd09a4]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo12PlanExecutor7getNextEPNS_7BSONObjEPNS_8RecordIdE+0x34) [0xbd0d54]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo12PlanExecutor11executePlanEv+0x3D) [0xbd13bd]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo18WriteBatchExecutor10execUpdateERKNS_12BatchItemRefEPNS_7BSONObjEPPNS_16WriteErrorDetailE+0x71D) [0x9b1bdd]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo18WriteBatchExecutor11bulkExecuteERKNS_21BatchedCommandRequestERKNS_19WriteConcernOptionsEPSt6vectorIPNS_19BatchedUpsertDetailESaIS9_EEPS7_IPNS_16WriteErrorDetailESaISE_EE+0x23C) [0x9b33bc]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo18WriteBatchExecutor12executeBatchERKNS_21BatchedCommandRequestEPNS_22BatchedCommandResponseE+0x37B) [0x9b38fb]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo8WriteCmd3runEPNS_16OperationContextERKSsRNS_7BSONObjEiRSsRNS_14BSONObjBuilderEb+0x15D) [0x9b62ad]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo12_execCommandEPNS_16OperationContextEPNS_7CommandERKSsRNS_7BSONObjEiRSsRNS_14BSONObjBuilderEb+0x34) [0x9d8474]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo7Command11execCommandEPNS_16OperationContextEPS0_iPKcRNS_7BSONObjERNS_14BSONObjBuilderEb+0xC1D) [0x9d93fd]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo12_runCommandsEPNS_16OperationContextEPKcRNS_7BSONObjERNS_11_BufBuilderINS_16TrivialAllocatorEEERNS_14BSONObjBuilderEbi+0x28B) [0x9da10b]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo8runQueryEPNS_16OperationContextERNS_7MessageERNS_12QueryMessageERKNS_15NamespaceStringERNS_5CurOpES3_+0x77A) [0xb9ef5a]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo16assembleResponseEPNS_16OperationContextERNS_7MessageERNS_10DbResponseERKNS_11HostAndPortE+0xB10) [0xab5290]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo16MyMessageHandler7processERNS_7MessageEPNS_21AbstractMessagingPortEPNS_9LastErrorE+0xDD) [0x80fc1d]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo17PortMessageServer17handleIncomingMsgEPv+0x34B) [0xf115bb]
 libpthread.so.0(+0x7DF5) [0x7f11765abdf5]
 libc.so.6(clone+0x6D) [0x7f117505a1ad]
-----  END BACKTRACE  -----
2017-11-14T04:39:35.113+0000 I CONTROL  ***** SERVER RESTARTED *****
2017-11-14T04:39:35.152+0000 W -        [initandlisten] Detected unclean shut
```

Comment: Have you tried through ">mongod --repair"

Comment: what MongoDB version, you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Rohit Bansal, I have gone through error log as i am able to see the error like

> **Invalid access at address: 0 Got signal: 11 (Segmentation fault)**

As per  `Kelsey T Schubert` from MongoDB Jira Blog [Here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-31236) This issue has been addressed in **SERVER-29850**, and the fix is included in **MongoDB 3.4.6** and later. Therefore, I would recommend upgrading to the latest version of MongoDB (`currently 3.4.9`) to resolve this issue.

Comment: Thanks Haidar. We were using mongo 3.0 and will give it a try